# How to add pattern and title in input

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have following code:

```
   <form>
       <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input"  name="CompanyName"/>
       <button id="ContinueButton_6">Continue</button>
   </form> 
   <script>
    let companyNameField = document.getElementById('FormField_6_input');
    companyNameField.setAttribute("pattern", "/[2-9]{1}\d{3}/");
    companyNameField.setAttribute("title", "invalid input");
   </script>
```

I want to add pattern and title attributes to my input but it not working please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Your code is OK. Just when is the JS code is supposed to get executed ? I mean after a click button or on document load ...

Comment: Are you getting any errors on console? Try to enclose it to execute on `document.ready()`

Comment: Your code is correct except for the regular expression. 1. You don't need forward slash when adding pattern 2. You need to escape backward slash.

Use: `.setAttribute('pattern', '[2-9]\\d{3}')`. Note that `{1}` is redundant and can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code please review.

```js
 
    let companyNameField = document.getElementById('FormField_6_input');
    companyNameField.setAttribute("pattern", "[2-9]\\d{3}" );
    companyNameField.setAttribute("title", "invalid input");
```

```html
 <form>
       <input type="text" id="FormField_6_input"  name="CompanyName"/>
       <button id="ContinueButton_6">Continue</button>
   </form>
```